# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$$

I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ diverges since the kth partial sum of the telescoping series can be written as:

$(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1})+(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})+(\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{3})+...+(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})=\sqrt{k+1}-1$

Then taking the limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$ of the kth partial sum gives me

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}=\sqrt{k+1}-1=\infty$

So this series is not absolutely convergent. But how can I check if it is conditionally convergent?

Intuitively I'm thinking if $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ diverges then
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ must diverge too. Is my logic correct here?

The solution says that this series is conditionally convergent but I'm not sure how they get that? Do I need to use the Alternating series test?

Answer (score 6):

It may help to rearrange the proposed general term as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{(n + 1) - n}{\sqrt{n + 1} + \sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1} + \sqrt{n}}
\end{align*}
which is a decreasing sequence of non-negative terms.

Finally, due the Leibniz test, the proposed alternating series converges.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: How did you know that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$ is a decreasing function?

Comment: @user130306 the denominator is the sum of two increasing terms, so is itself increasing.

Comment: Got it, thanks. so it's not absolutely convergent since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ and $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ diverges by the p-test. but it is conditionally convergent, since if we use alternating series test, $b_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}>0$ and $b_n$ is decreasing and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n = 0$

Comment: @user130306 It's correct $\sum\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ diverges and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ but it's not ensure that the series is not convergent. You need a series with $n-$ term $b_{n}$ such that $0<b_{n}<a_{n}$ with $\sum b_{n}$ divergent and $\sum a_n$ the series that you're studying here.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more general technique (though the one by [Átila Correia](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4432437/75808) is the simplest and probably best here):

> Suppose you have a (positive) sequence $(a_n)_n$, not necessarily monotone, such that
> $$
> a_n = b_n + c_n + O(c_n)
> $$
> where $(b_n)_n$ *is* non-increasing with limit $0$, and $(c_n)_n$ is absolutely convergent. Then $\sum_n (-1)^n a_n$ converges.

Indeed, you have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n a_n = \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n b_n + \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n (c_n+O(c_n))
$$
and on the RHS the first term will converge (by Leibniz's criterion) and the second will converge (absolutely) (by comparison with $\sum_n c_n$).

Now, in your case, $$\begin{align}a_n &= \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}
= \sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1\right) = \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{8n^2} + O\!\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) \\&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{8n^{3/2}} + O\!\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\end{align}$$
and you can apply the above with $b_n = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$, $c_n = -\frac{1}{8n^{3/2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $\displaystyle a_{n}:=(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$ so $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n}a_n$ converges because $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ is positive terms, decreasing (because the "denominator" increasing so "1/denominator" decreasing) and converges to zero and $(-1)^n$ is uniformly bounded by $1$ respect to $n$. However as you pointed out $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left|(-1)^n a_n\right|$ does not converges (alternatively for your solution in this part you can see $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|(-1)^{n}a_{n}|=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_{n} \geqslant \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ diverges) . So the series $\displaystyle 
 \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)$ is conditionally convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to rearrange by summarizing every two terms:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n (\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n}) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \sqrt{k + 2} - \sqrt{k + 1} - \sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k}$$
and using a telescope trick?